# What is difference between below two multithreaded java codes?

Tags: java, multithreading

Want to know difference between below two codes
My first code is

```
package com.app.myclasses;

class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
public class ThreadTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTest r1 = new RunnableTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "first");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1, "second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

In above code i have created two thread by using only one runnable instance
Now have a look at below code

```
package com.app.myclasses;
class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
public class ThreadTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTest r1 = new RunnableTest();
        RunnableTest r2 = new RunnableTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "first");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2, "second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

In second code i have created two runnable instances r1 and r2 and threads are created accordingly

So what is difference in above two codes? Is there any memory use issue or performance issue or one of them is not actually multithreading?

Comment: There is no difference. `RunnableTest` is not stateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Method local variables* are *implicitly thread-safe*. So, it doesn't matter in *your* case since `i` is *not-shared*.

Consider a case like this :

```
class RunnableTest implements Runnable {

 int i = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + i);
    }
}
```

}

Now,

```
class ThreadTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTest r1 = new RunnableTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "first");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1, "second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The above code will not give you correct output (0-4 twice). The output will be something like :

```
 first : 0
second : 0
first : 1
second : 2
first : 3
second : 4
```

We have *instance level* fields ( that are shared) here. So, the output is not what you expect.

In the other case, the *instance* level fields are not shared amongst threads. Since you have 2 different `runnables`.

If you want to synchronize *inside the runnable instance* and if you use `this`, then working on only `one instance` will be correct instead of `2 seperate runnable instances`.
 Note : Locking on the *runnable* instance is considered as bad design.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you have one instance of RunnableTest and so any instance variables will be shared by the two threads.  In the second case, there are two instances and so the threads will only share static data.

eg

```
class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
    static String shared = "Shared static data";
    String instance = "Instance data";
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + shared + " " + instance);
    }
    RunnableTest(String instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTest r1 = new RunnableTest("instance1");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "first");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1, "second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

gives

```
first Shared static data instance1
second Shared static data instance1
```

while

```
class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
    static String shared = "Shared static data";
    String instance = "Instance data";
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + shared + " " + instance);
    }
    RunnableTest(String instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTest r1 = new RunnableTest("instance1");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "first");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1, "second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

gives

```
first Shared static data instance1
second Shared static data instance2
```